# Check if $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1-\frac{1}{n}|x| & \text{ if } |x|< n \\ 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq n \end{cases}$ uniformly converges to $f=1$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I was asked to check if $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1-\frac{1}{n}|x| & \text{ if } |x|< n \\   0& \text{ if } |x|\geq n \end{cases}$  uniformly converges to $f=1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. The requirement is using the definition or theorem of the uniform distance between the functions.

***This is my try:***

First, I prove the sequence of function converges pointwise to the function $f=1$ for every $x$ as follows:

for $x=0$,$\forall n>0:f_n(0)=1-\frac{1}{n}|0|=1$, so  $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(0)=\lim_{n \to \infty}1=1$.

for $x\neq 0$, $\forall n>|x|: f_n(x)=1-\frac{1}{n}|x|$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}|x|\right)=1$

$\Rightarrow$ $f_n(x)\rightarrow f=1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now I check if $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ or not.

I get stuck here, since I'm not sure about the $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\sup}\left| f_n(x)-f \right|$.

Then, I come up with another idea: use counterargument! Assume $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$,i.e $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: n>N \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f|<\epsilon,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, let's choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$, then there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f|<\frac{1}{3}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let us choose $n=N$ and $x=\frac{N}{2}$. Then we have $|f_N(x)-f|=|1-\frac{1}{N}.\left| \frac{N}{2}\right|-1|=\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}=\epsilon$. This contradicts the hypothesis! So $f_n(x)$ does not uniformly converge to $f=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is my argument correct? What should I need to edit and modify? And how about using $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\sup}\left| f_n(x)-f \right|$ or the definition of uniform convergence directly! It's nice see your answer!

Comment: Your argument is correct. More quickly: $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\sup}\left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right|=1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval if you don't mind then can you explain your answer more detail? How can you get sup = 1? I always confuse with that! Thanks!

Comment: It is viewable as the maximal vertical distance between the graphs of $f$ and $f_n.$ Or algebraically: check that $0\le f-f_n\le1,$ so $\sup\le1,$ and (more importantly) $(f-f_n)(n)=1,$ so $\sup\ge1.$

Comment: You always have $|f_n(n)-f(n)| = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, since $(f-f_n)(n)=1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: from your explanation, it'll be correct if I understand in this way. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall n\geq |x|: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=|1-\frac{1}{n}|x|-1|=\frac{|x|}{n}\leq 1$ since $n\geq |x|$, and $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=1$ as $x=\pm n$. Thus, $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{sup}\left | f_n(x)-f \right |=1$. Right?

Comment: To be sure that (for a fixed $n$) the $\sup$ is exactly $1$ (and not greater) you must check that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\le1$ not only for every $x\in[-n,n]$ but also for $|x|>n$ (but that is easy: for those $x$'s, the difference is $0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval ah, now I understand! Thanks!